# Compost and Plumb the Forbidden

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens with copies of [Plumb the Forbidden](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Plumb%20the%20Forbidden) and [Compost](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Compost)? Do the copies count as cards that hit the graveyard?

Answer (score 6):

**No, copies of a spell do not trigger Compost because they are not cards.**

Copies of spells (and tokens) do go to the graveyard and can trigger all applicable abilities by doing that. They cease to exist the next time state-based actions are checked, but them changing zones is still a game event that happens.

However, Compost does not apply because Compost only triggers on black *cards* going to the graveyard. Copies of a spell are not cards, they're only objects without a card representing them.

> 706.10. To copy a spell, activated ability, or triggered ability means to put a copy of it onto the stack; [..] A copy of a spell is itself a spell, **even though it has no spell card associated with it.** [..]